# Evolution of second fundamental form

Tags: reference-request, riemannian-geometry, submanifold, foliations

For hypersurfaces, one classically computes the evolution (in the normal direction) of the area form as mean curvature, and the evolution of the mean curvature as the stability operator. I'm lucky enough to be in a case where I have a foliation of totally geodesic hypersurfaces. As such, I would like to compute something like the evolution of $|A|^2$ with $A$ being the second fundamental form of the hypersurface. I'm sure this is well-known, but I'm having trouble pinning down a reference to check my calculations. Does anyone know of any?

Comment: If your hypersurfaces are totally geodesic, their second fundamental forms vanish, so I'm not sure what you are asking actually

Comment: Right one side should vanish. The other side should just be a standard computation - so $0=\delta |A|^2=?$ My computation is a bit messy, so I'd like to double check.

Comment: This will depend on what relates your hypersurfaces. See *Geometric evolution equations for hypersurfaces*, Huisken and Polden.

Comment: Thank you for the reference!

Comment: Perhaps you could show us your calculations?

Comment: @Deane For me, it turns out it's enough to instead consider $0=\partial_t A_{ij}=\phi R(\nu,i,\nu,j)-\langle\nabla_i(\nabla_\Sigma \phi),j\rangle+\phi A_{ij}A_{kj}$ for $\partial_t=\phi\nu$, then take unit speed $\phi$ to get $R(\nu,i,\nu,j)=0$ for all $i,j$. I orginally hoped to argue $R\equiv 0$ though this method, but looking at the second ff should give only normal information not tangential.